# Matrix antidiagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

I was just thinking about if there exists any way to antidiagonalizate a matrix. I mean given A, finding a antidiagonal matrix J such that

$\pmatrix{v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots\\ v_n} = \pmatrix{0 &\dots& 0&\lambda_{1,n} \\ 0 & \dots & \lambda_{2,n-1} & 0 \\ \vdots && &\vdots& \\ \lambda_{n,1} & \dots & 0 & 0}$ $\pmatrix{v_1 \\ v_2 \\ \vdots\\ v_n}$.

The only thing I thought was that if $\lambda_{n,k}$ is an antieigenvalue of A then $\lambda_{n,k}\cdot\lambda_{k,n}$ is an eigenvalue of $A^2$.

Any references? Thanks!

Comment: $v_1$ here is scalar or row vector?  If scalar your equation is very easy to solve,

Comment: Where’s J here? Do you mean to have $J=MAM^{-1}$ for some invertible M? What have you tried? Are you familiar with Jordan Normal form and blocks?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The $J$ appears exactly once, is it the matrix with the $\lambda$-indexed entries? If so, can you antidiagonalize first a diagonal matrix? (By using a permutation like $(1n)(2,n-1)\dots$ which reverses the order...) Then if we can diagonalize, we can also antidiagonalize. Whatever this may be good for...